# how to set an extra cookie after login successful in spring security

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security

I want set an extra cookie after user login successful. after read the source code of `AbstractProcessingFilter`, I found that it fire an `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` after login. so I can write an `ApplicationEventListener` for this, but how can I get the corresponding `HttpServletResponse` in the event listener?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of things you should override:

```
AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(
  HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response,
  Authentication authResult)
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I add this bean to `applicationContext-security.xml`, the rememberme config lost (compare with `<http auto-config="true">`), and now I have switched to spring security 3.0, which can use `<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="foo">`